# How to backup sqlite3 from heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite

I want to backup sqlite3 file in heroku server.
With a command `heroku db:pull sqlite:///Users/ironsand/backup.db`, I got a error.

```
 !    `db:pull` is not a heroku command.
 !    Perhaps you meant `pg:pull`.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
```

It seems `db` command isn't available anymore and I couldn't find a way to backup the sqlite database from heroku.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db:push` and `db:pull` are now deprecated, instead you should use [Heroku PGBackups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups)

Also, note that, ***heroku does not support SQLite database. You must have been using sqlite3 locally but for production (heroku) you are using PostgreSQL.***

To backup your database from heroku and download the backup, follow the following steps:

create a backup:

```
heroku pg:backups capture --app your_app_name
```

create a publicly accessible backup URL:

```
heroku pg:backups public-url --app your_app_name
```

Then, curl it down and save it to `db_backup.dump` file:

```
curl 'the_db_backup_url' > db_backup.dump
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but both ways failed for my environment. And new way to backup are only using postgresql. I gonna change database to postgres, but I want to backup the sqlite3 database first.

Comment: Please follow these instructions to get the backup: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#downloading-your-backups
Those things are deprecated now.

Comment: oh, It seems I misunderstood totally. I'll check again and follow your instruction. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer and also updated your question to reflect that. FYI.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are trying is deprecated please try the below one

heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA mylocaldb --app sushi

ref:- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-pull

Comment: Thanks, but the link you introduce me was about backup of postgresql, not about sqlite3. I need to know a way to backup sqlite3.

Comment: You are using sqlite3 db locally, but on heroku its postgresql. Heroku does not support sqlite3. See my updated answer.